# Call powershell script and dont wait for it to return

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I have a Jenkins job which I want it to run a powershell script.

The Powershell is a long process that can take a while, I want the Jenkins to Invoke the powershell and not to wait for it to finish

I tried to run the powershell with

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock
```

but once Jenkins job finishes it closes the powershell.
I simply want to lunch and forget

Comment: FYI: There's discussion for such a feature in Jenkins here: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26052.   For PowerShell specifically you can use `start-process -FilePath 'powershell.exe' -ArgumentList '-Command "1..10000 | %{write-host $_;Start-Sleep -Seconds 1}"'`, replacing the script in Command with whatever script you want to run (or by using the `-File` parameter to point to a different script file).  Another workaround option is to use Jenkins to create a job in the Windows Task Scheduler, which can then kick off your task.

Answer (score 3):

There may be a powershell specific way to do this, but a ghetto solution I've used in the past is to call the script with `cmd.exe /c start`

From the cmd.exe help:

`/C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates`

Using this method, the cmd.exe process will run, start your powershell script in a new process, then terminate, leaving the powershell script running in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Run a command to start PowerShell with [`-noexit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/core-powershell/console/powershell.exe-command-line-help#-noexit) like this:

```
start powershell -noexit -file "D:\MyToolkit\ToolKit.ps1"
```